# Distributing topics between worker instances with minimum overlap

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, rabbitmq, distributed-computing

I'm working on a Twitter project, using their streaming API, built on Heroku with Node.js.

I have a collection of topics that my app needs to process, which are pulled from MongoDB. I need to track each of these topics via the API, however it needs to be done such that each topic is tracked only once. As each worker process expires after approximately 1 hour, when a worker receives SIGTERM it needs to untrack each topic assigned, and release it back to the pool again.

I've been using RabbitMQ to communicate between app and worker processes, however with this I'm a little stuck. Are there any good examples, or advice you can offer on the correct way to do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "with this I'm a little stuck"? What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the worker just send a message via the messagequeue to the application when it receives a SIGTERM? According to the [heroku docs on shutdown](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm) the process is allowed a couple of seconds (10) before it will be forecefully killed.

So you can do something like this:

```
// listen for SIGTERM sent by heroku
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {

    // - notify app that this worker is shutting down
    messageQueue.sendSomeMessageAboutShuttingDown();

    // - shutdown process (might need to wait for async completion
    // of message delivery to not prevent it from being delivered)
    process.exit()
});
```

Alternatively you could break up your work in much smaller chunks and have workers only 'take' work that will run for a couple of minutes or even seconds max. Your main application should be the bookkeeper and if a process doesn't complete its task within a specified time assume it has gone missing and make the task available for another process to handle. You can probably also implement this behavior using [confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) in rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ won't do this for you.

It will allow you to distribute the work to another process and/or computer, but it won't provide the kind of mechanism you need to prevent more than one process / computer from working on a particular topic.

What you want is a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) - a way to control access to a particular "resource" from multiple processes... a way to ensure only one process is working on a particular resource at a given time. In your case the "resource" will be the topic... but it will still be the resource that you want to control access to.

FWIW, there has been discussion of using RabbitMQ to implement a distributed semaphore in the past:

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2014/02/19/distributed-semaphores-with-rabbitmq/
- https://aphyr.com/posts/315-call-me-maybe-rabbitmq

but the general consensus is that **this is a bad idea**. there are too many edge cases and scenarios in which RabbitMQ will fail to work as proper semaphore.

There are some [node.js semaphore libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=semaphore) available. I would recommend looking at them, and using one of them. Have a single process manage the semaphore and decide which other process can / cannot work on which topic.